# Retina Macbook Pro 13 & Linux VMs?

Tags: macos, macbook

im in search of the perfect ultrabook for me. Tried an HP Spectre for about a month and found out i wasn't quite happy with it. The high res display (2560x1440) is really nice but causes problems in linux VMs (with VMWare Workstation 10). The text is extremely small to the point that its unusable. Anyways that along with the fact that i'm starting really not like Windows 8 i've decided to go the Macbook route. I'm thinking on getting a Macbook Pro Retina 13.

My main question is if i will have the same type of resolution issues with linux vms (probably will be using parallels) that i had with windows with the retina screen? If so i might end up getting a macbook air instead.

Answer (score 0):

The fact that the VM's appear to have text too small is not because the laptop has too high of a resolution, but because the appropriate drivers were not installed.

Inside the linux vm, you will need to install the accompanying software (often called VMWare tools or Guest Box additions).

You can further control the resolution in the virtualization software you are using. See this [KB Article](http://kb.parallels.com/en/114700) for parallels.

I routinely run man VMs in both virtual box and VMWare fusion on my retina mac. The resolution appears too small/big until I install the appropriate software and restart the VM.

Comment: thanks for the comment but in my case it was VMWare workstation 10 (with the tools installed) and Lubuntu and it still didn't work correctly. Hopefully the story works better with Lubuntu installed in Parallels on the rMBP i just ordered.